# File download error only in file name with Comma

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-stream

In my file download API case an error like this.

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:380)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:405)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96)
    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:128)
    at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:109)
    at
```

I notice that the error only occurs when trying to download a file with a name containing comma(,) otherwise it works perfectly.

In my API I set the response like this:

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader(Constants.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename= " + fileSeedName);
                        System.out.println(file.exists());
                        FileCopyUtils.copy(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)), response.getOutputStream());
response.flushBuffer();
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known issue specific to Google Chrome specifically related to the Content-Disposition header. According to numerous references (just Google “Chrome content-disposition comma”), this is caused by the fact that chrome doesn't properly handle escaping of commas while Firefox, IE, etc. do. According to a few sites, this was introduced relatively recently and Google doesn't plan on fixing it.

Reference [link](https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/d8348e07fe5e441183bae07dfda00e40/Comma-in-file-name-cause-problem-in-Chrome-Browser)

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the Chrome bug-tracker issue where this is reported? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link you can refer : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=937802

Answer (score 16):

Wrap the filepath in "Double Quotes"

Answer (score 11):

the filename need double quotes to work

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename="' . $fileName . '.pdf"');
```

Comment: This is the actual fix.

Comment: Confirming this is still true in 2023 -- wrapping the filename in double quotes fixed the "MULTIPLE CONTENT DISPOSITION" error we were seeing from filenames containing commas even with the latest version of Chrome.