# S3 Presigned URL - filename provided in Content Desposition for generating Presigned URL, getting error while downloading

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Trying to download a file from AWS S3 using presigned Url , and i set the file name in Content Desposition.
The file name is having comma " , " . while i tried downloading this file using that presigned URL, got this error in Browser ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION. Here is my java code.

```
ResponseHeaderOverrides override = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
       
             
        override.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename="+ "BM, EN-POP, SWP - 8P GUK A.pptx");
        GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(Bucket_name,S3_Object)
             .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
             .withExpiration(expiration)
             .withResponseHeaders(override);`
```

the Generated presigned URl is:

https://BUCKETNAMEamazonaws.com/S3OBJECT?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3DBM%2C%20EN-POP%2C%20SWP%20-%208P%20GUK%20A.pptx&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200914T142744Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=56&X-Amz-Credential=AKIA6HDPIVH2Z7PVP4SY%2F20200914%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=1095c99c6d9ad83a9d14d2af89d064ac420783f6a58f0071537b4d623d02d546

Anyone having any idea, the comma in the filename mentioned in content-Desposition can not be replaced.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003459. Also, disposition != deposition.

Comment: got it seems like this is a known issue. thanks  @jarmod